# Is there one photon per wavelength of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons

This makes intuitive sense to me but I have never heard anyone confirm it. Is it one photon per wave length or does it approximate one wavelength or something else?

Comment: What does "one photon per wavelength" mean?

Comment: [What are photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253957)